# Left Join in Query containing Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, left-join

I want to fetch from the following tables the Customers who have ordered at least two Products. The tables are:

```
Customer(Id, Name, City),
Product(Id, Name, Price),
Orders(Customer_Id, Product_Id, Date)
```

I use the query

```
select c.*
from customer c
join orders o on o.customer_id = c.id
group by c.id
having count(o.customer_id) >= 2
```

It returns the expected results, but when I replace the `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` it still provides the same results. It does not returns all the rows of the Customer table as stipulated by `LEFT JOIN`. Why is the functionality of `LEFT JOIN` limitted in this occassion? Due to the fact that someone cannot distinguish the results which come from a match from the ones that appear only in the left table?

Comment: You are using a filter on the table `orders`? (it's the `having` that you are using`, basically making the `left join` an `inner join`

Comment: do you have a fiddle with sample data that proves this?

Comment: If you are only interested in customers with at least 2 products why do you want a left join? That would preserve customers with zero orders (that you then eliminate in the `having`)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LEFT JOIN works as expected but you have other things that affect the *result of the join*.

In particular, your HAVING clause only accepts customers that have two or more matches in the `orders` table (`COUNT(o.customer_id) >= 2`). Surely, if a customer has no orders, it will be returned by the LEFT JOIN operation but will be filtered out by HAVING – because `COUNT(o.customer_id)` would evaluate to 0 for them.

If you want to return customers that have at least two orders *or* customers that have none, just say so in the query, either like this:

```
select c.*
from customer c
left join orders o on o.customer_id = c.id
group by c.id
having count(o.customer_id) >= 2
   or count(o.customer_id) = 0
```

or even like this:

```
select c.*
from customer c
left join orders o on o.customer_id = c.id
group by c.id
having count(o.customer_id) <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

o.customer_id is null in those instances where there is no corresponding row in the order table.  COUNT only counts non-null values.  Try COUNT(1) or COUNT(c.customer_id) and see if you get the desired results.

Comment: it won't make a difference if he uses `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(c.customer_id)`, since he is grouping every column from the `customer` table, so he won't get more than one row unless it actually has multiple rows on table `Orders`

Comment: With having count(c.id) >= 2 or count(1) the results are exactly the same. Only the rows that match are in the result group.

Comment: You are right. It isn't the left join that's limiting the results.  It's the HAVING clause.

Comment: Correct. As Lamak points out, with the left join you will still only have 1 record per customer when the customer has no order records, so COUNT(c.id) or COUNT(1) will still be equal to 1 for those customers, which fails the HAVING restriction.